# Arduino Yun not showing anything on the serial monitor

Tags: sensors, servo, adafruit

I am having issues with the ArduinoYun. It's not showing any data in the serial monitor. The sensor lights up when I plug it in but that's about it and the code seems to compile but nothing is coming through. I am using the Adafruit color sensor. I have SDA/SCL connected to pins 4 and 5. The servo is connected to pin 3. The rest is just on Vin and GND.

```
#include "Servo.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"

const int redPos = 160;
const int orangePos = 130;
const int yellowPos = 100;
const int greenPos = 70;
const int bluePos = 30;
const int nonePos = 0; // Kein Objekt erkannt

Servo myservo;

Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725(TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_50MS, TCS34725_GAIN_1X);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Makerblog.at - MuMs Color Sensor");
  if (tcs.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Sensor gefunden");
  } else {
    Serial.println("TCS34725 nicht gefunden ... Ablauf gestoppt!");
  while (1); 
  }
  // Der Servo hängt am PWM-Pin 3
  myservo.attach(3);
  // Servo in Grundstellung fahren
  myservo.write(0);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  uint16_t clearcol, red, green, blue;
  float average, r, g, b;
  delay(100); // Farbmessung dauert c. 50ms
  tcs.getRawData(&red, &green, &blue, &clearcol);
  average = (red+green+blue)/3;
  r = red/average;
  g = green/average;
  b = blue/average;

  // Clear-Wert und r,g,b seriell ausgeben zur Kontrolle
  // r,g und b sollten sich ca. zwischen 0,5 und 1,5
  // bewegen. Sieht der Sensor rot, dann sollte r deutlich über 1.0
  // liegen, g und b zwischen 0.5 und 1.0 usw.
  Serial.print("\tClear:"); Serial.print(clearcol);
  Serial.print("\tRed:"); Serial.print(r);
  Serial.print("\tGreen:"); Serial.print(g);
  Serial.print("\tBlue:"); Serial.print(b);

  if ((r > 1.4) && (g < 0.9) && (b < 0.9)) {
    Serial.print("\tROT");
    myservo.write(redPos);
  } else if ((r < 0.95) && (g > 1.4) && (b < 0.9)) {
    Serial.print("\tGRUEN");
    myservo.write(greenPos);
  } else if ((r < 0.8) && (g < 1.2) && (b > 1.2)) {
    Serial.print("\tBLAU");
    myservo.write(bluePos);
  } else if ((r > 1.15) && (g > 1.15) && (b < 0.7)) {
    Serial.print("\tGELB");
    myservo.write(yellowPos);
  } else if ((r > 1.4) && (g < 1.0) && (b < 0.7)) {
    Serial.print("\tORANGE");
    myservo.write(orangePos);
  } else {
    Serial.print("\tNICHT ERKANNT");
    myservo.write(nonePos);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code works, you should be able to change the position of the servo by altering the initialized color values.  Currently they are:

```
 const int redPos = 160;
 const int orangePos = 130;
 const int yellowPos = 100;
 const int greenPos = 70;
 const int bluePos = 30;
 const int nonePos = 0;
```

If, for example, the positions of Red and green are to be swapped all that is needed is to alter the code like this:

```
 const int greenPos = 160;
 const int orangePos = 130;
 const int yellowPos = 100;
 const int redPos = 70;
 const int bluePos = 30;
 const int nonePos = 0;
```

The numbers, according to the [Arduino's servo driver web page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo), are the angle in degrees the servo will be moved to after executing the [call to the Arduino servo driver](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWrite).

Given the above, if a new color violet were to be added to the original set of colors the first change would be to move the servo positions slightly higher to make room for the new color.

```
 const int redPos = 160;
 const int orangePos = 135;
 const int yellowPos = 110;
 const int greenPos = 85;
 const int bluePos = 60;
 const int violetPos = 35;
 const int nonePos = 0;
```

The next change would be to alter the ranges of the color test code.  As you did not specify what hardware you are using to detect colors, you will have to experiment to find the combination of red, green & blue which matches the new color violet.  The code used for detecting blue is:

```
 else if ((r < 0.8) && (g < 1.2) && (b > 1.2))
```

Likely violet contains more red and may be detectable with a line of code like this:

```
 else if ((r > 1.0) && (g < 1.2) && (b > 1.2))
```

The position of this test may be important depending on how the detector works.  It may be best to place it after testing for orange.  Remember to use the new initialized variable such that you code may look like this:

```
else if ((r > 1.0) && (g < 1.2) && (b > 1.2)){
  Serial.print("\tVIOLET");
  myservo.write(violetPos);
}
```

Comment: you are the best, thank you so much for breaking down the code for me.

Comment: Well, i am having issues with the arduino yun, showing any data in the serial monitor. The sensor lights up when i plug it in but that is about it and the code seems to compile but nothing is coming through.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen anyone edit a question like that.  My recommendation is to change back your question to its original wording.  Then post a new question about not getting the expected results.  Add a comment here if you can not figure out how to change your question back to its original form & I will try to do it.  By the way, you should try the original Adafruit example code and verify your hardware is connected properly and is working before trying unknown code.

Comment: I tried using the example codes in the arduino ide but i was still having the same issue. i read other post and they said that it had to do with using serial.begin instead of consol.begin.I found that suggestion impractical to my situation since i was not using wifi for the yun, i attempted using console.begin anyways just to see whether that would help but it did not. so, i am still having the same issue.

Comment: We can't have a discussion in the comments.  The "stackexchange bots" will start suggesting we move.  But I would test the code w/o the servo in an ordinary situation where the example code works.  Then dropping printing out the color and just use the detector and servo and finishing off your testing.